# AngularJS - UI-Router does not load view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm in an app that uses `angular-route` and I'm trying to integrate `ui-router` into a particular module.  In this module, I have not included `angular-route`.

The `ui-sref` urls will all generate fine, but when a user tries to navigate to the view, it kicks back to root.

Can `angular-route` and `ui-router` co-mingle?

```
angular.module('StyleGuide', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/StyleGuide/');

        // Configure UI-Router
        $stateProvider
            .state('styleguide', {
                url: '/StyleGuide/',
                templateUrl: 'App/StyleGuide/styleguide.html'
            })
            .state('styleguide.sandbox', {
                url: '/StyleGuide/Sandbox',
                templateUrl: 'App/StyleGuide/sandbox/sandbox.html',
                controller: 'SandboxController'
            });
    }
  ]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sgHeader">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <nav class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown open" uib-dropdown >
                    <a role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
                        <li><a ui-sref="styleguide.sandbox"><i class="fa fa-hourglass-start"></i>Sandbox</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="styleguide"><span class="heavy">Soar </span>Styleguide</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sg__body" ui-view>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>The Soar Style Guide, this is.</h1>
        <h3>Use it to promote codebase and visual consistency, you will.</h3>
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/49/7d/80/497d80f923e70aaa558d17c9cd1ee142.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with a rogue `otherwise` statement in another module.

Answer (score 0):

In the child State - 'styleguide.sandbox' change the URL from '/StyleGuide/Sandbox' to '/Sandbox'. Since you have already mentioned sandbox to be a child of styleguide, the router will automatically treat the URL for sandbox as '/StyleGuide/Sandbox', you don't have to specifically mention it.

Comment: I still have the same issue.  When accessing the `/StyleGuide/` url, it just forards to `/` root